# How do I make my UITableView Scroll?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In the following code, I push a new UITableView when I click on a button.  The TableView has 25 rows.  I can see the first 9 row and the 10th row got cut off.  I can't scroll down to view the rest of the rows.  How do I make the TableView scrollable?  Thank you.

```
- (IBAction)showListPicker:(id)sender {
    ListPicker *lp = [[ListPicker alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [self setTitle:@"Home"];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:lp animated:YES];
    [lp release];
}
```

The following is the declaration for ListPicker

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ListPicker : UITableViewController
{}
@end
```

The following is the implementation for ListPIcker

```
#import "ListPicker.h"
#import "GameStore.h"
#import "List.h"
#import "HomeViewController.h"

@implementation ListPicker

- (id)init
{
    return [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
}

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style{
    return [self init];
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [self setTitle:@"Select List"];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[[GameStore defaultStore] allLists] count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"] autorelease];
    }

    NSArray *allList = [[GameStore defaultStore] allLists];
    List *mylist = [allList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSString *listTitle = [mylist label];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:listTitle];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    List *list = [[[GameStore defaultStore] allLists] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[GameStore defaultStore] setSelectedList:list];

    HomeViewController *hv = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


@end
```

Comment: not sure if related to the problem, but in your implementation of `initWithStyle:` you probably want to do `return [super initWithStyle:style];` instead of `return [self init];`

Comment: does it bounce at all? or is the table completely fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add:

```
yourTable.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

Also, when you create your table programmatically, make sure it is "long enough", i.e.,

```
CGRect cgRct = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600);          
yourTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:cgRct style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Comment: where do add the above code to? from within (IBAction)showListPicker:(id)sender?

Comment: typically in your viewDidLoad, but I am not seeing any here...perhaps where you initialize everything in your view controller. In general, I would advise you to use a UIViewController rather than a UITableViewController, and add all this programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **YES**, write **true** as it accepts only bool values.

```
yourTable.scrollEnabled = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Two common ways to change the boolean state of scrolling in a UITableView:

1) It can be enabled either in the attributes inspector of the UITableView via Storyboard.

[image]

2) Or programmatically inside your viewDidLoad() via ViewController.

```
import UIKit  

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet var yourTable: UITableView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // assign delegate and datasource 
            yourTable.delegate = self
            yourTable.dataSource = self

            //enable UITableView scrolling in Swift 3 and Swift 4.
            yourTable.isScrollEnabled = true
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.